# What file name placeholders are available for Serilog?

Tags: .net, logging, filenames, serilog

I use Serilog on a .NET Core application with RollingFile. I wonder, if there are different filename placeholders? I only know {Date}.

For example, I have code like

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile("Logs/{Date}.log")
            .CreateLogger();
```

Are there any other options for the filename like {Date}? I'd like to have log files by hour.

Comment: Can a date based filename be configured in appsettings.json?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the time of this writing, Serilog's Rolling File sink supports 3 (three) specifiers:

- `{Date}`, which is formatted as `yyyyMMdd`
- `{Hour}`, which is formatted as `yyyyMMddHH`
- `{HalfHour}`, which is formatted as `yyyyMMddHHmm`

You can see it in the [README of the Rolling File sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile#filename-format-specifiers), as well as in the [source code of the Rolling File sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile/Sinks/RollingFile/Specifier.cs).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just could not find any documentation.

Comment: It's in the README for the rolling file sink: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile#filename-format-specifiers

Comment: (We might need an index of READMEs somewhere :-))

Comment: Thanks again. Thumbs up for the index issue ;-)

Comment: So with rolling file sink obsolete, is this possible with the file replacement?

Comment: Did that and ended up with this filename: {Date}-log20231010.txt

Doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE : 2022**

Because "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" is obsolete now you should use "Serilog.Sinks.File"
It's as easy though :

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

This will append the time period to the filename, creating a file set like:

```
log20180631.txt
log20180701.txt
log20180702.txt
```

For differentes choices :

[image]

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add environment variables into the appsettings.json as %USERNAME%